# SonarQube report showing a different coverage than Gitlab RSpec (Ruby) report

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, code-coverage

Just as the title implies we're dealing with an "issue" regarding the information shown in SonarQube for our Ruby Code Coverage when we compare it to the Gitlab Pipeline job execution given that in the Pipe execution it's showing

[image: Gitlab Pipeline Job execution for Coverage Report]

*as you can see it shows 91.21% coverage/covered*

While in SonarQube we're getting the following result:
[image: SonarQube Coverage percentage]

Which is weird given that they are both supposedly taking reading the same report

We're using **SimpleCov 0.21.1** and only made some minor adjustment to the report in order to avoid using the "branches" feature that came after simplecov 0.18+.

Maybe those are 2 different values and not related at all and I'm getting it all wrong? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated :')

Thanks a lot in advance and happy holidays for everyone !